# Why HTTP Methods are also called "Verbs"

Tags: rest, http, restful-architecture

I've seen that HTTP methods are often called *Verbs*. 
(I understand the correct name is Methods from: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231 )

Where did this name come from ?

Comment: Because the words GET, POST, PUT, DELETE are all, in fact, [verbs](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/verb).

Comment: @levininja always bothered me that OPTIONS isn't (and HEAD isn't used as a verb semantically).

Answer (score 8):

The use of the spelling `Method` dates back to at least 1996, where it appears in [section 5 of RFC 1945](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-5.1.1).   That's in agreement with [Basic HTTP as defined in 1992](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/HTTP2.html) (which appears to be a retrospective from 96 or 97).

The alternative spelling `Verb` doesn't appear to have any official sanction.  It's probably derived from English speakers picked a name that made sense to them when looking at an example of a [request line](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.1.1) without being familiar with the spec.

You would, perhaps, expect that the audience looking at representations of HTML forms would have noticed that the spelling of the attribute was `METHOD`, but the [telephone game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers) happened.  Such is life.

Comment: @VoiceOrUnreason thanks, this is awesome. I'm interested as to why you use the word "spelling"? Is this some other subtlety of HTTP that I don't know about, or could you have said "word" or "name"?

Answer (score 3):

- The HTTP verbs comprise a major portion of our “uniform interface” constraint and provide us the action counterpart to the noun-based resource.
- The primary or most-commonly-used HTTP verbs (or methods, as they are properly called) are **POST, GET, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE**.
- These correspond to create, read, update, and delete (or CRUD) operations, respectively. There are a number of other verbs, too, but are utilized less frequently. Of those less-frequent methods, OPTIONS and HEAD are used more often than others.

Reference : http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html